mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer returns INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER on Google Pixel but not on Samsung Galaxy
I am trying to convert some bitmaps to video and encode them with this library https://github.com/israel-fl/bitmap2video
In the FrameBuilder.kt, it encodes a given into AVC/H264.
However, dequeueOutputBuffer, at the end of the stream, will return -1/INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER, on my Google Pixel Pixel 6 Pro, but it works fine on Samsung S21/S22. Why is that?
Output for Pixel 6 Pro
15:00:30.299  I  event=androidx.camera.video.VideoRecordEvent$Status@3b2c59b
15:00:30.327  I  event=androidx.camera.video.VideoRecordEvent$Status@ee2077
15:00:30.588  I  event=androidx.camera.video.VideoRecordEvent$Finalize@d1a4d13
// I get the URI for the recorded video and parse it to the MediaRetriever, 
// where I extract the bitmap-frames for encoding
15:00:30.589  I  uri=content://media/external/video/media/1000000258
15:00:35.046  D  drainCodec(false, encoderStatus=-1
15:00:35.058  D  drainCodec(false), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.435  D  drainCodec(false), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.457  D  drainCodec(false), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.480  D  drainCodec(false), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.493  D  drainCodec(false), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.506  D  drainCodec(false), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.516  D  releasing encoder objects
12:35:03.516  D  drainCodec(true), encoderStatus=-1
12:35:03.516  D  sending EOS to encoder
12:35:03.527  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:35:03.537  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:35:03.549  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:35:03.560  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:35:03.571  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:35:03.583  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
~ continues indefinitely

Samsung S21 logs:
12:49:05.493  I  qqq uri=content://media/external/video/media/1000026049
12:49:14.362  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.396  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.442  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.492  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.494  D  encoder output format changed: {max-bitrate=1500000, crop-right=2159, level=32768, mime=video/avc, profile=8, bitrate=1500000, priority=0, intra-refresh-period=0, color-standard=1, csd-1=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8], color-transfer=3, crop-bottom=3839, prepend-sps-pps-to-idr-frames=0, video-qp-average=0, crop-left=0, width=2160, bitrate-mode=1, color-range=2, crop-top=0, frame-rate=30, height=3840, csd-0=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=22 cap=22]}
12:49:14.498  D  {max-bitrate=1500000, crop-right=2159, level=32768, mime=video/avc, profile=8, bitrate=1500000, priority=0, intra-refresh-period=0, color-standard=1, csd-1=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8], color-transfer=3, crop-bottom=3839, prepend-sps-pps-to-idr-frames=0, video-qp-average=0, crop-left=0, width=2160, bitrate-mode=1, color-range=2, crop-top=0, frame-rate=30, height=3840, csd-0=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=22 cap=22]}
12:49:14.507  D  ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG
12:49:14.509  D  sent 6605 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.510  D  sent 1255 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.517  D  sent 2901 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.548  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.578  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.579  D  sent 7208 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.610  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.611  D  sent 10116 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.646  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.648  D  sent 18212 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.678  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.679  D  sent 14077 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.711  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.712  D  sent 13230 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.745  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.746  D  sent 13348 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.778  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.778  D  sent 14504 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.796  D  drainCodec(false)
12:49:14.804  D  sent 14219 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.814  D  releasing encoder objects
12:49:14.814  D  drainCodec(true)
12:49:14.814  D  sending EOS to encoder
12:49:14.825  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:49:14.828  D  sent 12867 bytes to muxer
12:49:14.838  D  no output available, spinning to await EOS
12:49:14.843  D  end of stream reached

drainCoded function
    private fun drainCodec(endOfStream: Boolean) {
        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "drainCodec($endOfStream)")
        if (endOfStream) {
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sending EOS to encoder")
            mediaCodec.signalEndOfInputStream()
        }
        while (true) {
            val encoderStatus: Int = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC.toLong())
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "encoderStatus=$encoderStatus")

            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet, stuck here on Google Pixel
                if (!endOfStream) {
                    break // out of while
                } else {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no output available, spinning to await EOS")
                }
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
                if (frameMuxer.isStarted())  throw RuntimeException("format changed twice")
                val newFormat: MediaFormat = mediaCodec.outputFormat
                Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: $newFormat")

                // now that we have the Magic Goodies, start the muxer
                frameMuxer.start(newFormat, audioExtractor)
            } else {
                val encodedData = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus) ?: throw RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer  $encoderStatus was null")
                if (bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG != 0) {
                    // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                    // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG")
                    bufferInfo.size = 0
                } else {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "Flags not configured")
                }
                if (bufferInfo.size != 0) {
                    if (!frameMuxer.isStarted()) throw RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started")
                    frameMuxer.muxVideoFrame(encodedData, bufferInfo)
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sent " + bufferInfo.size + " bytes to muxer")
                } else {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "No bytes sent")

                }
                mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false)
                if (bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM != 0) {
                    if (!endOfStream) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "reached end of stream unexpectedly")
                    } else {
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "end of stream reached")
                    }
                    break // out of while
                }
            }
        }
    }



I can see that the status is -1 even before calling signalEndOfInputStream(). Does the encoder produce any output buffers (on the Pixel device)?

Well the encoding would start when the status is not -1, right? at line frameMuxer.muxVideoFrame(encodedData, bufferInfo). So if it starts at -1, the encoder cannot encode right? Or maybe I am misunderstanding.. how can I test if it produces any buffers?

Do you see any logs with "sent X bytes to muxer" on Pixel?

No, unfortunatly :( That would only happen if the initial status was not -1

Can you share the beginning of the log?

Sure, updated the logs and added a comment

Did you try to increase the timeout?

Tried upping it to 10_000_000, still returns -1 on first drain

Are there any errors in the logcat?

Not that i can see, just the endless loop. More logs: https://pastebin.com/raw/CWRGvZg9

If you have a pixel phon, I have a working example: https://github.com/Mikkelet/bitmap2video/tree/issues/XX-try-again-google-pixel

IMHO you shouldn't drain the codec right after starting it. You won't get output buffers until you queue some input buffers.

So should I apply a delay before calling drain? Why does it work fine on Samsung phones? I actually also tested it on my colleagues Pixel 7.. and same thing happened. Maybe its the Tensor chip?

IMHO you should only call drainOrRelease after unlockCanvasAndPost.

Okay, I tried removing it from the start(), that way it's only called after unlockCanvasAndPost. Same thing happens

What does the log look like now?

Just a sad, endless stream encoderStatus=-1

The log in the Pastebin appears to be from Samsung, not Pixel. It shows c2.exynos.h264.encoder, which is a Samsung's codec.

Another thing: lockHardwareCanvas() could be causing the problem. Try to use only lockCanvas().

Its definitely from my pixel: https://imgur.com/UAsf9S1

I tried using lockCanvas, but that creates other problems. On Samsung, the muxer doesnt start (doesnt receive format changed from dequeueOutputBuffer) and Pixel does not output the encoded frames to the file. :S
